# Center align boxes inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got the following box design.

[image]

These green color boxes are dynamically generated inside "col-md-10" div. In the second row, if there is no 3 boxes I want to center align the boxes. In the following case I want to have "Bi-monthly" box right underneath "Weekly" box.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: show us code not image

Comment: I assume that `col-md-x` is a bootstrap selector, as I remember it uses `float` in order to align the row.
You can use the `flex-box` version of bootstrap grid in order to achieve your requirement.

Comment: what bootstrap version are you using? also, are you married to the idea of inline styling for each box?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='col-md-10 text-center'>
  <div class='col-md-4 text-center'>1</div>
  <div class='col-md-4 text-center'>1</div>
  <div class='col-md-4 text-center'>1</div>
  <div class='text-center center-block' style='width: 33.33333333%;'>1</div>
</div>
```

This is something I have done using bootstrap 3.x. This works fine. You cannot have the class name `col-md-4` for the 4th block. Try this. It works.

In this example, `text-center` and `center-block` are bootstrap classes.

Also, try to minimize the use of inline styles. Because, in bootstrap, there are built-in class names for all these things. If you are using bootstrap, make use of it completely. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

[image]

```
<article class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 img">...</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 img">...</div>
</article>

article{
text-align:center;
}

article .img{
display: inline-block;
float: none;
vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Please try to see if this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> These green color boxes are dynamically generated inside "col-md-10" div

So you need to check condition your dynamic data length , I hope you want to display 3 block in a row then if there is one block in a row you want to set in center . You need to check dynamic data length and divisible 3 to check that can be a single block ....
In below I used `col-xs-4` because stackoverfow snippet display is too small ....

```js
var data = ['One','Two','Three','Four'];
var last = data.length - 1;
data.forEach((v,i) => {
  var div = "<div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-4 col-md-4 bg-info '>"+v+"</div>";
  
  if((last == i) && (i % 3 == 0)) {
    div = "<div class='col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4 col-md-4 bg-info '>"+v+"</div>";
  }
  
  $(".test .row").append(div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 test"><div class="row"></div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are using Bootstrap.

But you can approach this very elegantly and concisely using CSS Flexbox.

**Working Example:**

```css
ul {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin: 0 0 60px;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

li {
flex: 0 0 calc(33vw - 36px);
margin: 6px;
padding: 6px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<h1>Keep Scrolling down...</h1>

<ul>
<li>One-off</li>
<li>Weekly</li>
<li>Fortnightly</li>
<li>Bi-monthly</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>One-off</li>
<li>Weekly</li>
<li>Fortnightly</li>
<li>Bi-monthly</li>
<li>Quarterly</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>One-off</li>
<li>Weekly</li>
<li>Fortnightly</li>
<li>Bi-monthly</li>
<li>Quarterly</li>
<li>Half-yearly</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<div class='col-md-10 text-center'>
      <div class='col-md-4 text-center'>1</div>
      <div class='col-md-4 text-center'>1</div>
      <div class='col-md-4 text-center'>1</div>
      <div class='col-md-4 offset-md-4'>1</div>
    </div>
```